# A word to describe the act of using one's head to moving slowing to the sex partner body while having sex

Tags: single-word-requests

I have to translate this from my language but i don't know in english.

While someone having sex, he may moving his head wander around his partner's body.
What is the words to describe this action.

Comment: I have no idea what you're describing

Comment: Using one's head is impotant at **all** times, esp. at times like this. Voting to close.

Comment: I can also be recognized as stimulating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want **[nuzzling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nuzzle?s=t)**:

- thrusting the nose, muzzle, etc.
- lying very close to someone or something; cuddling or snuggling up.